# How to pass variable values from a Client's Menu Widget to Server Map's GameMode?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I have a Game default map which has a widget. The players have 2 options, Create a session or join a session which is triggered with 2 buttons in the menu (Host and Join). In the menu, also the player selects the level he wants to play and number of players against which he wants to play. Once he selects map and enter number of players against which he wants to play, he clicks host button which will open level (in Ip Address) containing the server map which is a lobby. In the lobby gamemode, I have condition which will check if the lobby has n number of players that the host player has input in the menu before and then will load the level that the host player has selected in the menu before. The only problem which is frustrating me right now is the fact that I am not able to pass those menu variables to the server map (lobby) gamemode. I have tried options with OpenLevel and Casting values to Game Instance. but none is working with dedicated server. How exactly should I tackle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variables inside your menu will be destroyed once you enter a new level. You could keep them by using the game instance. This persists over levels and will not reset after a level change.

Comment: I tried game instance. It's also not working as after the menu level, I am connecting to the game dedicated server. The solution you mentioned work for a listen server. But not for Dedicated server